# How to pause recording using AudioQueues in iPhone?

Tags: objective-c, voice-recording, audioqueue

I am using AudioQueue for recording voice.
 I want to know how can we pause the recording ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there is:

```
AudioQueuePause(audioQueue);
```

where audioQueue is the reference to your AudioQueue.  For more information, check out the Audio Queue Services Reference for [iPhone](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/DOCUMENTATION/MusicAudio/Reference/AudioQueueReference/Reference/reference.html) or [Mac OSX](http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/MusicAudio/Reference/AudioQueueReference/Reference/reference.html).